# JavaScript. Image Rollover

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a java script code so that when I moves the mouse over one of the three images that are shown, the current image is replaced by a new one. **First: I want to create a event handler for the mouse enter event of the image element. I want this handler to change the src attribute of the image element so it point to the url for the rollover image.**
**Second: I have to write a mouse out event. This handler should return the src attribute of the images element to the original image**

Here is the html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Image Rollovers</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
    <script src="rollover.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
 <section>
  <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
  <ul id="image_rollovers">
      <li><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="images/h4.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="" id="images/h5.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="" id="images/h6.jpg"></li>
     </ul>        
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner to do this with CSS:

```css
#img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://placebear.com/200/200");
}

#img:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/200/200");
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
```

But if you really want to use the event listener approach:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img');

img.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  this.src = "https://placekitten.com/200/200"
})

img.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  this.src = "https://placebear.com/200/200"
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/200">
```